# How to get the Collector Assault Rifle?

Tags: mass-effect-3

How do I get to use the Collector Assault Rifle? I had it in ME2 and I kinda like the look of it :)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Collector Assault Rifle is unfortunately not directly present in the game.

If you are preordering *The Art of the Mass Effect Universe*, or if you buy a *Mass Effect 3-branded Razer gaming accessory*, you will get a code that will unlock you this weapon, but only in the Multiplayer game.

*Source*: [Mass effect Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Collector_Assault_Rifle)

Comment: Your Welcome! Good Luck in the last furlong to travel!!

Answer (score 2):

You can make changes to your save file using ''gibbed me3 save editor'' [download here](http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/) so that the collector rifle is available in single player too:

1. open a save file with editor
2. select the `raw` tab
3. navigate down to `/ - 4. Plot /Player variables`, and click little square button <kbd>...</kbd> on the right of (Collection). a new window will pop-up.
4. press <kbd>Add</kbd>. look to the right at the table with two rows.
5. paste this into the **Name** field: `SFXGameContent.SFXWeapon_AssaultRifle_Collector`
6. change the nubmer zero in **Value** field to: `1`
7. press <kbd>Add</kbd> to add one more entry
8. paste this into the **Name** field: `SFXGameContent.SFXWeapon_AssaultRifle_Collector.Flags`
9. change the nubmer zero in **Value** field to: `1`
10. click <kbd>OK</kbd> and the window closes
11. save the changes to a new savegamefile by clicking <kbd>save</kbd> at the top icon bar.

Launch game, load the new save and play with collector!